# C Python arbitrary argument

Tags: python, c, python-c-api

in plain python (2.7) one can write variadic function like so:

```
>> def myfunc(a, b, *args):
    print a,b,args

>> params = (1,2,"3", "abc")

>> myfunc(*params)
# Will print "1 2 ('3', 'abc')"

>> myfunc(params)
# Will fail with 'myfunc() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)'
```

When writing a Python extension in C, I can pass a tuple of PyObjects (like params in the example) easily, but how can I pass params with the `*`-operator with function such as `PyObject_CallMethodObjArgs` and the likes.

Comment: You mean you want to know how to pass in `params` as separate arguments from C code, like `*` would?  Does [Passing variable number of arguments around](//stackoverflow.com/q/205529) apply here?

Comment: [`PyObject_Call`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_Call)?

Comment: Please clarify how you want to call the function. Do you just want the equivalent of `myfunc(*params)`?